# backup database prior to deployment in pipeline

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, sql-server-data-tools

Is there a first-class citizen* way to **backup** the DB **before** deploying the *dacpac* in a Azure DevOps pipeline (yaml not classic gui)?

If there isn't an "easy button", how do I do this?

Reference: [WinRM SQL Server DB Deployment task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group)

---

*When I saw first-class citizen, I mean **not** rolling my own custom solution but using a generic solution provided by the MSFT eco-system.

Answer (score 1):

How are you creating your dacpac? There is a sqlpackage option to backup database before deployment, and there are numerous ways of specifying it. [You can specify it on the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlpackage/sqlpackage-publish?view=sql-server-ver16), with `/p: "BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges=True"`, or you can specify it in your publish profile in your database project. Right-click the project => publish => Advanced => "Backup database before deployment", then save the profile in the project.

[image: Backup database before deployment]

If you're using the using the 'SQL Server database deploy' task in Azure, you can put `/p: "BackupDatabaseBeforeChanges=True"` in the additional arguments box.
[image: SQL Server database deploy on Azure]

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I did it, using an inline PowerShell script, in my Azure Pipeline:

```
Write-Host "Backing up database: $(DatabaseName) on $(DatabaseServer)"
Write-Host ""

# Backup to a filename like "MikesDatabase_20231201.bak"
$sqlBackup ="BACKUP DATABASE [$(DatabaseName)] TO DISK = '$(BackupDbLocation)\$(DatabaseName)_ymd.bak' WITH COMPRESSION, INIT, SKIP, STATS=10 "
$sqlBackup = $sqlBackup.replace("ymd","$(get-date -f yyyyMMdd)");

Write-Host "Running Invoke-Sqlcmd backup command:"
Write-Host $sqlBackup
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "$(DatabaseServer)" -Database "$(DatabaseName)" -Query "$sqlBackup"  -Verbose
Write-Host ""
```

In my Azure Library, I have three variables defined:

- DatabaseServer
- DatabaseName
- BackupDbLocation

... so I can modify these, per environment.

Answer (score 0):

### Source control side

1. add a sql script to the DB project, `backup.sql`
2. set the build action to `none`

*backup script*

```sql
EXECUTE dbo.DatabaseBackup @Databases = '__DbName__'
    ,@Directory = '__DbBackupLocation__'
```

### Build side

1. add that file to the ADO artifact

```yaml
steps:
- publish: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/db-backup.sql
  artifact: DB Artifact
```

reference: [Publish artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts)

### Library side

1. in a variable group, add variables for `DbName` & `DbBackupLocation`

reference: [Create a variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group)

### Deployment side

*assumption:* you're using a `deployment` task so the artifact(s) are automatically downloaded; reference: [Artifacts in release and deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts)

1. import the variable group; reference: [Use a variable group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#create-a-variable-group)
2. call the replace token task from [qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task](https://github.com/qetza/vsts-replacetokens-task)

```yaml
steps:
- task: replacetokens@3
  displayName: DB Untoken
  inputs:
    rootDirectory: $(Pipeline.Workspace)\DB Artifact\
    targetFiles: *.sql
    tokenPrefix: __
    tokenSuffix: __
```

3. use [SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group) to execute `backup.sql`

```yaml
steps:
- task: SqlDacpacDeploymentOnMachineGroup@0
  displayName: DB Backup
  inputs:
    taskType: sqlQuery
    sqlFile: $(Pipeline.Workspace)\DB Artifact\db-backup.sql
    serverName: localhost
    databaseName: master
    authScheme: windowsAuthentication
    additionalArgumentsSql: -Verbose -Querytimeout 0
```